# How to add response headers in Simple-httpd

Tags: server, web

I ran Simple-httpd emacs webserver that was described on https://github.com/skeeto/emacs-web-server site. I used the code

```
  (use-package simple-httpd
    :ensure t
    :config
    (setq httpd-root "/home/u/Dropbox/js-proj")
    (setq httpd-port 8081))
(httpd-start)
```

Then I tried to add some response headers but not succeed.
The code was this

```
  (use-package simple-httpd
    :ensure t
    :config
    (setq httpd-root "/home/u/Dropbox/js-proj")
    (setq httpd-port 8081)
    (httpd-send-header t "text/plain" 200 :Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"))
(httpd-start)
```

I wanted to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` but also tried with fake headers `:Foo "bar"` and did not succeed too. So maybe I should use the function `httpd-send-header` in a different way?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info